# How to make a button to do some operation or change to another view?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

help me please. how to make a button to do some operation or change to another view? I want that by pressing on it, commands were complete then need that moved on another view. please tell me how else to do to another kind in which a transition is updated when you press the button, all the same. And there were set data from datamodel

```
@IBAction func addNew(sender: AnyObject) {
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Items", inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext!)
    var item = Items(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext)

    // I make the init from row coredata
    item.titleIt = titleItem.description
    item.textIt = textViewItem.description

    var error: NSError?
    managedObjectContext?.save(&error)
    // MasterViewController.setValue(Items(), fromKey: "titlIt")


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this at the end of your method:

```
let viewControllerToGoTo = ClassNameOfViewController() 
self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Note: You may need to instantiate the view controller you want to present in a different way than just `()`. For example, you may want to load a view controller defined in a nib or storyboard.

Comment: please tell me how else to do to another kind in which a transition is updated when you press the button, all the same. And there were set data from data model.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. There are a ton of examples on presenting view controllers out there.

Comment: when there is a transition to another controller when this button is pressed, I would want that the controller will automatically update the data in Table View

Comment: If you're presenting another view controller, it will be a completely different `UITableView` (or at least should be unless you're doing something weird). That new table view will reload its own data automatically the first time the view loads.

Comment: Sorry, but you got me wrong, I have a presentation after another controller receives an error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value", After pressing the button which I have previously.

Comment: That's something entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

To move to another view controller, you write these lines:

```
var viewController = ViewControllerNew()
self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But if you want to pass data to another view, I'd recommend using this method instead:

In your storyboard, select the view controller and drag from the blue-outlined yellow square at the top of the view controller to another view controller. A popup will appear, showing a list of segues. Select the item named 'Show'. Segues are placeholders for presenting view controllers -- you can call them at any time in your program. Select the segue, and under the menu on the right hand side type a name, for example 'toOtherScreen' into the text field labeled 'Identifier'. This will let you call the segue from a specific name.

Now go back to your IBAction for the button, and type this:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toOtherScreen", sender: self)
```

This will transition to the other screen. But what if you want to pass data to a screen, or do something when a segue is about to happen? Luckily for you, UIViewController class has a method named 'prepareForSegue', as shown below:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
     if segue.identifier == "toOtherScreen" {
       println("yes")
     }   
}
```

In this, we check if the segue has an identifier of "toOtherScreen", and if so, print "yes" to the logs. Now, to pass data to another view controller, it is a little more tricky. In the other view controller file, add a variable at the start of the class:

```
class OtherViewController: UIViewController {

  var dataPassed: String = ""

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }


}
```

And in your prepareForSegue method in the main view controller, type this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
     if segue.identifier == "toOtherScreen" {
       let newViewController = segue.destinationViewController as OtherViewController()
       newViewController.dataPassed = "NEW DATA"

     }   
}
```

Now it will change the variable named dataPassed in OtherViewController to 'NEW DATA'. You can see how you can achieve a lot through this simple way of passing data to other view controllers.

Hope I helped.